# How do ERP/MRP systems handle product variations (options)?

Tags: erp

This question revolves around how business functionality is to be partitioned between off-the-shelf ERP/MRP systems and other systems including custom developed programs or modules. We could build the latter, but why do so if off-the-shelf can avoid that custom effort, maintenance etc?

The area I'm hoping to gain an understanding of is whether ERP/MRP systems customarily function as an enterprise authority on product structure (variations and options, not to mention versioning of same), and if so, how sophisticatedly.

As a concrete example, a company manufactures various electronic equipment, one line being laptops. Like with Dell or Lenovo, a laptop product line consists of a base model, and then a set of options or variables, each of which offers two or more choices.  Example: Laptop offers screen options (high res; low res; TFT; OLED), and battery options (standard; high capacity), and so on for possibly dozens of feature areas. Some options themselves can have subsidiary options.

I have seen that some ERP/MRP systems include "Configurator" functionality that offers sales people (or, online, end customers) all these product options and their choices, to allow them to configure specific products to be purchased, assembled, and delivered.

But in some systems I have looked at more closely, in the Configurator UI, the available options are essentially hard coded (well, coded in program statements by programmers), as is the link to the BOM items that need to be assembled to manufacture the configured product.  The Configurator is based on program statements rather than being driven by data.

[Edit: Here I mean that configurator screens are programmed with custom code, possible by the business's programmers, or by consultants. Not fixed programming by the ERP vendor.]

And because that product structure information is captured as program code, it's not readily available for other purposes, such as reporting, linking to other data like PLM, catalogs, coordinating the internal configurators and web-facing eCommerce or B2B, and so on.

Now it's difficult to assess the current state of play in the industry, as many vendors only offer this level of insight into their products once engaged in the sales process, and even then only after digging through levels of non-technical sales personnel.

So I'm hoping that others here can shed some light on whether this matter of managing product structure data is customarily incorporated into at least some ERP/MRP systems, or is it generally expected to be handled externally in some other manner?

(For purposes of this question, assume ERP/MRP systems offered for businesses in the less-than-$50M range, so Tier II or below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a general question, so the answer is also generic one and contains *personal opinions*:

I've rarely found product structure information coded into programs. It might be the case of very small development, or just the **worst strategy**. Coding product structure in program is *criminal*. Any standard MRP/ ERP solution can not survive with this approach beyond a few tiny implementations, so let's discard and forget this approach.

Most ERP/ MRP solutions are based on the concept of SKU, Item Code or Materials. This is where the problem starts for configurable products. Since vendors have to sale it to different customers (in same or even different industries - cable, textile, automobile, electronics for instance), they've to:

- Provide structures to map characteristics/ attributes/ properties/ components
- Provide structures to map possible options, values, measurements, restrictions for those characteristics etc.
- Provide mapping of those values to components (which could be a simple or again a configurable material)
- Provide flexibility to enter possible values at run time with necessary restrictions and at times with a unit of measurement
- Provide dependency of characteristics/ options/ components/ operations
- Implement business rules based on stock and availability, planning schedules, production capacity etc.

Most standard ERP solutions provide dedicated but generalized functions to map these via combination of SKU, Configuration and Bill of Materials, SOP (recipe or routings). The *generalization* of this functionality facilitates coverage of more industries, but is bound to mess up table structures, code base and standard reporting. If you look at the relevant table structures for configurable product in one of leading ERP solution, you'll be surprised to realize inefficiency under the carpet (CODD will cry!). In most large implementations, the complexity and volume increase and these ERP just cannot handle this all. So they've dedicated optimizer or planner solutions to handle forecasting and material planning. You'll find both generic optimizer from same vendor or *certified* third party add ons.

By the time, customer scenarios are mapped and taken in live environment, every dependent functionality and report will seem dysfunctional! Customers don't understand the problem and vendors know the answer based on past experience (but concealed from uninformed clients)- more computing resources! Vendors tend to cover these inefficiencies and suggest powerful servers, load distribution and balancing and similar techniques. This goes on and customers keep learning in the process.

Some other ERP / MRP vendors choose not to generalize this and focus on an industry and gain confidence of one industry or very similar industry. This distinction (same or similar industry) is tricky - what works in yarn textile may not work in raw cloth textile and what works in raw cloth textile may not work in ready-to-wear textiles! All have product with options and falls under textile industry. There are many smaller but focused solutions for textile, automobiles, paper industry that work pretty well in that industry. The functionality is generally neatly implemented but restricted to one industry only. Performance is generally good and resource requirements are moderate since these solutions are already focused on single industry.

Lastly, customer may decide to take things in own hand and go for custom development. Again you'll look for customer's product specifications and provide table structures to cover these variants. But never code product structures or options in program even is the smallest implementation - *make it table driven*.  Unless very good functional and technical resources are deployed on these developments, they're most likely in development phase for ever.

Products with variants and options are not a simple scenario. Whether you look for standard ERP solutions, industry solutions or custom development, you'll need to research a lot and some of the learning will come only with experience. I've reason to believe that *less than $50m* boundary is secondary issue in above scenarios. I've seen and been part of all three type of solutions (*the big* ERP solution with Variant configuration, Industry Solution and Optimizer; industry focused solution from a moderate vendor and custom solutions with third party development team as well as by in-house development team; dedicate industry optimizer integrated in custom solution) and all have their *pluses* and *minuses*. *Every implementation* needs careful evaluation.

If you ask my experience, the standard ERP solution (probably you know what I'm referring to) are generally misfit in process *-like* industry (textile, paper, packaging) but reasonable to some extent in discreet *-like* industry (automobile, electronics, assembly). Industry specific solutions from focused vendor are likely to be most effective solution, if the industry has one! Custom ERP development for an industry with configurable products is not less than delivery of a baby - lot of planning, energy and pain in the process, but a happy family at the end - more predictable outcome in case of a baby, less in case of custom solution development. *I'm a happy father of two such babies! Second baby is more healthy and much stronger, as expected!!*.

> So I'm hoping that others here can shed some light on whether this matter of managing product structure data is customarily incorporated into at least some ERP/MRP systems, or is it generally expected to be handled externally in some other manner?

Yes, most **reasonable** ERP systems have capability to map product options. An ERP/ MRP solution based on just plan SKU's is feasible only in smaller industry with fewer than few hundred variants and combinations. When it comes to MRP, most ERP systems rely of add-on solutions for configurable products.